# Nested Loop with program, boolean arrays?

Tags: java, loops

In the constructor of the model class, I need to allocate the memory of this array of booleans (boolean[ ][ ] is_hidden;). I also need to set them to true, but have no idea how this happens, a nested loop will have to be used like the one in the paint method at he bottom, in order to set each element.

```
class MineFinderModel {
public static int MINE_SQUARE = 10;
public static int EMPTY_SQUARE = 0;

int num_of_cols;
int num_of_rows;
int[][] the_minefield;
boolean[][] is_hidden;

public MineFinderModel(int n_cols, int n_rows) {
    num_of_rows = n_rows;
    num_of_cols = n_cols;
    the_minefield = new int[num_of_cols][num_of_rows];
    is_hidden = new boolean[][];
}
```

Paint method example:

```
                   for (int i = 0;i<numCols;i++)
         {
        for(int j = 0;j<numRows;j++)
        {
            Rectangle r = getRect(i,j);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g2.draw(r);

            if(i==0&&j==0)                                  {
                g2.drawOval(x,y,w,h);
            g2.fillOval(x,y,w,h);
            }
            if(i==0&&j==(numRows-1))
            g2.fillOval(x,y,w,h);

            if(i==(numCols-1)&&j==0)
            g2.fillOval(x,y,w,h);

            if(i==(numCols-1)&&j==(numRows-1))
            g2.fillOval(x,y,w,h);
```

Comment: Yes, you need a nested loop - and you need to initialize the array to be the right size, just like you do with `the_minefield`. Now, what difficulties are you having with those two aspects?

Comment: "a nested loop will have to be used" that is correct. Or do you mean you do not understand what a "nest loop" is?

Comment: Sounds like you already know the solution (using loops) so what are you asking for?

Comment: I seem to be getting a problem within my constructor

Comment: is_hidden = new boolean[][]; says array dimension error, how?

Comment: array dimension missing

Comment: `new boolean[some integer][some integer]` to specify the dimensions of the array.

Comment: Now add two public methods to get and set the values of this new array: public void uncover(int thisCol, int thisRow)The uncovermethod changes the state of the specified square to false. Otherwise, if the input co-ordinates are outside the minefield or the square is already uncovered, it does nothing. public boolean isCovered(int thisCol, int thisRow)The isCoveredmethod returns true if the specified square is covered. Otherwise, if the input co-ordinates are outside the minefield or the square is not covered, it returns false.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the array with the sizes e.g.

```
is_hidden = new boolean[cols][rows]();
```

and iterate through, setting each cell to `true` (booleans, and boolean arrays, default to `false`).

Note that [Arrays.fill()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28boolean%5B%5D,%20boolean%29) exists, but will only get you halfway, since it won't fill multidimensional arrays. You can use this, but you'd have to iterate through the rows, and use `Arrays.fill` on each row. Perhaps not worthwhile in this example, but worth being aware of regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    int num_of_cols = 2;
    int num_of_rows = 3;
    boolean[][] is_hidden;
    is_hidden = new boolean [num_of_cols][num_of_rows];

    for (int i = 0; i < num_of_cols; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < num_of_rows; j++) {
            is_hidden[i][j] = true;
        }
    }
```

You can see it is now correctly initialized:

```
    for (boolean[] col : is_hidden) {
        for (boolean elem  : col) {
            System.out.println(elem);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

when you define a boolean array the value of all the elements are false by default.
 I would suggest instead of looping through all the elements, implement your conditions in way that you can use the default false value.

Eg.

```
boolean[][] isEnabled =  new boolean[10][10];
// code to set all elements to true
if(isEnabled[i][j]){
    //some code
}
```

this can be easily replaced by

```
boolean[][] isDisabled =  new boolean[10][10];
if(! isDisabled[i][j]){
    //some code
}
```

You can save processing time this way and code looks neat :).

Answer (score 0):

Simply write a nested loop.

```
for (int i = 0;i<n_rows;i++){
    for(int j = 0;j<n_cols;j++){
        is_hidden[n_rows][n_cols] = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution for you: instead of using your array is_hidden and fill each element of it with true, use the name isVisible and don't fill it at all since every element of it is already initialized to false ;)